# dlopen, factory pattern and the virtual method table

Tags: c++, factory-pattern, dlopen

I'm trying to wrap my head around how the factory pattern works internally when using dlopen in c++. Sorry for long post.

tl;dr; Question is in **Bold** below.

Snippets from http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/thesolution.html with error checking removed to save space:

main.cpp

```
#include "polygon.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main()
{
    using std::cout;

    // load the triangle library
    void* triangle = dlopen("./triangle.so", RTLD_LAZY);

    // load the symbols
    // create function pointers
    // (Exposed with extern "C")
    polygon* create_triangle = (polygon*) dlsym(triangle, "create"); 
    void* destroy_triangle = (void*) dlsym(triangle, "destroy");

    // create an instance of the class
    polygon* poly = create_triangle();

    // use the class
    poly->set_side_length(7);
    cout << "The area is: " << poly->area() << '\n';

    destroy_triangle(poly); // destroy the class

    dlclose(triangle);     // unload the triangle library
```

}

polygon.hpp

```
#ifndef POLYGON_HPP
#define POLYGON_HPP

class polygon
{
protected:
    double side_length_;

public:
    polygon()
        : side_length_(0) {}

    virtual ~polygon() {}

    void set_side_length(double side_length)
    {
        side_length_ = side_length;
    }

    virtual double area() const = 0;
};

// the types of the class factories
typedef polygon* create_t();
typedef void destroy_t(polygon*);

#endif
```

triangle.hpp

```
#include "polygon.hpp"
#include <cmath>

class triangle : public polygon
{
public:
    virtual double area() const
    {
        return side_length_ * side_length_ * sqrt(3) / 2;
    }
};


// the class factories

extern "C" polygon* create()
{
    return new triangle;
}

extern "C" void destroy(polygon* p)
{
    delete p;
}
```

So looking at the main() function what I see is this.

1. dlopen creates a handle.
2. Function pointers created so that the triangle class can create a new triangle object and destroy it. (dlopen is giving us a memory location to branch to.)
3. create_triangle() returns a triangle casted into a polygon (since we know the methods of the polygon.
4. We set the internal member side_length_ using the base class's set_side_length method.

**Here is the question:**

**When poly->area() is called how is this found in the triangle object?**

- We know where in memory the base class has it's "virtual area()" method.
- Since "triangle.so" is dynamically loaded, the compiler isn't able to say on I recognize that the triangle area() is overriding the polygon area() in your program.
- The names are completely mangled at this point and the .so could have been compiled with clang++ and the program could have been compiled with g++. So potentially having no hope of recognizing them at this point.

Does the Virtual Member Table keep the virtual methods in order according to when they appear? So would this code break it?

polygon.hpp

```
...
virtual double area() const = 0;
virtual double parameter() const = 0;
...
```

triangle.hpp

```
...
double parameter() const { ... } // implementing and defining parameter first
area() const { ... } // implementing and defining second.
...
```

I know you would want to keep them in order... but let's say we subclass a couple more times and they get defined in a different order...

Any help on this would be great. I just can't visualize what is going on in the memory here to make this actually work.

Thanks! And sorry for the long post.

Comment: FYI, the specificities of how VTables are constructed, located, how names are mangled, etc. is called the compiler's *ABI*. Different compilers typically have incompatible ABIs, but Clang tries hard to play nice with GCC on that point.

Comment: Changing the order member variables are declared in can break stuff, and schanging access e.g. private to public, but these are all ABI questions. You mention the compile (for finding things at run time) - once you return a pointer to a polgon the vtable is baked in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When poly->area() is called how is this found in the triangle object?

All initialization of `poly` happens inside the library (including setting the vptr). The only thing that caller (i.e. executable) has to do is to load virtual method pointer from `poly`'s vtable at particular index. Both executable and shlib share the declaration for `poly`'s class so they both agree which vtable element corresponds to `area`.

Note that compiler does not need to know *anything* about how implementation of `poly` overloads the base class.

> the .so could have been compiled with clang++ and the program
>   could have been compiled with g++

Clang would struggle really hard to be ABI-compatible with GCC on Linux platforms (with Visual Studio on Windows platforms) to achieve this kind of interoperability.

> I know you would want to keep them in order... but let's say we subclass
>   a couple more times and they get defined in a different order...

Subclassing wouldn't change the structure of base class vtable which is fixed at this point (otherwise polymorphism would break as well).

Comment: Thanks! This makes much more sense, since the library is creating `poly`, it would know how to integrate everything together. The library is doing all the "heavy lifting" of making the object, the caller basically recognizes the public "interface" (if i can use that word loosely). Basically the caller doesn't care about the vtable because the object (created by the library) manages itself.

Answer (score 1):

Note that to increase inter-compiler compatibility (and also safety), I would recommend to make the interface (`polygon`) destructor **protected** and **non-virtual**.

#### Why protected

In general the dll does not necessarily need to have the same heap as the application using it (this is especially the case when used between different compilers), therefore you should disallow calling `delete` on the interface (that is also why you are providing the `destroy()` function).

#### Why non-virtual

This is just for a technical reason, because the virtual destructor is frequently implemented differently under different compilers. One example is the incompatibility between MSVC and MinGW (GCC) under Windows - MSVC creates one virtual table entry for the virtual destructor, whereas GCC creates 2 entries for it. Which makes the virtual table shifted by one item. With (inline trivial) non-virtual destructor there is no entry in the virtual table for the destructor.

---

Additionally, instead of providing an extra `destroy()` function, I normally provide a pure virtual `destroy()` method in the interface itself (with the impl simply calling `delete this;`). Optionally with an inline wrapper, which tests if the interface pointer is not NULL (because obviously calling virtual method on NULL pointer will not work). And in best case optionally wrapped in a smart pointer which actually takes care about calling `obj->destroy()`.

Comment: Frankly I wouldn't advise people to try MinGW/MSVC C++  interop - this will likely have many more ABI problems besides virtual dtors.

Comment: @yugr Yes, in general it would be indeed better to implement "own virtual tables" via pure C calls, which would be completely safe for inter-compiler interop. However, according to my experience the GCC/MSVC interop via very basic pure virtual interfaces works in general (with some limitations - e.g. no exceptions passing, no virtual method overloading which could have different ordering, no multiple inheritance, etc.).